# DNF fails to synchronize cache when using --installroot option

Tags: linux, fedora, dnf

I am trying to install a bunch of software in a dummy root, so I can copy it into new systems quickly. However whenever I use *dnf install* or *dnf builddep* with the *--installroot* option it fails to synchronize cache for repositories.

I thought it's missing some configuration, so I copied yum and dnf configuration files into the installroot dir:

```
cp /etc/dnf/dnf.conf     /path/to/root_fs/etc/dnf
cp /etc/yum.conf         /path/to/root_fs/etc/
cp -R /etc/yum.repos.d/  /path/to/root_fs/etc/
```

But still what I get is

```
sudo dnf -c $ROOT_FS_DIR/etc/dnf/dnf.conf install gcc --installroot=$ROOT_FS_DIR -releasever=23
Error: Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'updates'
```

Dnf works fine updating my host system.
So how do I configure dnf to install packages into a different root dir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DNF is not so clever and needs a `releasever` if you installs in chroots ([bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1173107)). You miss single `-` in front of that option:

```
sudo dnf -c $ROOT_FS_DIR/etc/dnf/dnf.conf install gcc \
  --installroot=$ROOT_FS_DIR --releasever=23
```

but the release 23 is already [EOL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/End_of_life) so the mirrors do not have to exist anymore. You should use supported release version.

Comment: Oh my, what a mistake... Thank you!